# Can we perturb a product of linear terms so that we keep the local geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I am trying to understand the following phenomenon. Let me give an example first to elaborate my idea.

Let $Q(x,y)=(y-x)\cdot (y+x)\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. If we look at the zero locus of $Q(x,y)$ in the real space $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is just two straight lines intersecting at the origin. Now if I perturb $Q$ by adding some higher order terms with degree greater than the degree of $Q$, for example, $\tilde{Q}(x,y)=Q(x,y)+x^3$, then locally at the origin the zero locus of $\tilde{Q}$ will still look like the zero locus of $Q$ in the real space.

This is not in general true in three variables. For example, $P(x,y,z)=xy$ will have different local geometry at the origin with $P(x,y,z)=xy-z^3$.

Now let me rephrase all of them in a more formal way. Suppose that we have a polynomial $\tilde{Q}(z_1,\cdots, z_d)$ in $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\cdots,z_d]$ and the leading homogenous part of $\tilde{Q}$, deonoted by $Q$, is a product of $m$ distinct linear terms $L_i$, each of which vanishes at the origin. Can we factor $\tilde{Q}$ in the local ring of analytic germs at the origin, namely $\mathbb{C}\{z_1,\cdots,z_d\}$? Or more precisely, can we write $\tilde{Q}$ as
$$ \tilde{Q} = u(z_1,\cdots,z_d) \prod_{i=1}^m P_i(z_1,\cdots,z_d)$$
where $u$ and $P_i$ are in $\mathbb{C}\{z_1,\cdots,z_d\}$, $u$ is a unit, and $P_i(0,\cdots,0)=0$, $\nabla P_i(0,\cdots,0)=\nabla L_i(0,\cdots,0)$.

This is always the case when $d=2$ and $Q$ is made of distinct linear terms. For example, $\tilde{Q}(x,y)=(y-x)\cdot(y+x) +x^3$ can be factored as $(y-x\sqrt{1-x})(y+x\sqrt{1-x})$. Actually I cannot find a reference to it and so I prove it.

This should not be true in general for $d>2$. I wonder if there is any literature on this kind of problem. In particular, I want to know at what conditions, such factorization exists or not exist.

I am barely new to algebraic geometry and the only thing I find similar is something called "normal crossing divisor" in Janos Kollar's $\textit{Lectures on Resolution of Singularities}$.

Comment: To rephrase your question (when m \leq d and the linear terms L_i are linearly independent): You are asking for the equisingular deformations of a normal crossing singularity. Of course, as you have observed, not all deformations of a normal crossing singularity need be normal crossings.

Comment: @PhilipEngel Thanks for your comment. Are you suggesting that if we impose the requirement that $m \leq d$ and $L_i$ linearly independent, then the question is the equisingular deformations of a normal crossing singularity? Do you have any references on this type of problems?